# ExecutorService inside an IntentService. Will it be killed by Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, intentservice

I wrote an IntentService that I am going to use to download some heavy data from the web (large images mostly).

The class looks like this:

```
public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

    public UpdateService() {
        super(UpdateService.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        List<ListenableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Runnable r : getRunnables()){
            executorService.execute(r);
            futures.add(r.getFuture());
        }

        Futures.addCallback(

                Futures.allAsList( futures ),

                new FutureCallback<List<Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Boolean> result) {
                        // do some logic here
                        executorService.shutdown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        // do some error handling here
                        executorService.shutdown();
                    }
                }
        );      

    }
}
```

As you can see the `onHandleIntent()` method returns quite quickly since most of the activity is executed within the *Runnables* executed by the ExecutorService.

Will android kill the IntentService and consequently kill the threads started by the `ExecutorService` after some time that the `onHandleIntent()` method is returned?

Or does it somehow *detect* that threads still exist and the Intent Service is still alive?

In case, how to change the code to prevent Android from killing the service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will android kill the IntentService

The `IntentService` will destroy itself, via `stopSelf()`.

> and consequently kill the threads started by the ExecutorService after some time

The threads are leaked, but they will run, until the process is terminated. Since you no longer have a `Service` telling Android that your process is doing work, your process could be terminated quite quickly.

> how to change the code to prevent Android from killing the service?

Do not use `IntentService`. Use `Service`, and call `stopSelf()` yourself once all your threads are done with their work.

Comment: Thanks, perfectly explained